# Trying to save values from webservice into core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to save values obtained from the webservice which i have added it into a dictionary then trying to save the dictionary into the core data. When I debug the values are in the dictionary but they are not being added into the core data. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

The code I use to put it in the dictionary then save it to my core data is

```
    for (id gradedWorkDictionary in _gradedworks){
        NSLog(@"Converting to object: %@", [gradedWorkDictionary valueForKey:@"Title"]);
        ListOfGradedWorks *gradedWork = [[ListOfGradedWorks alloc] initWithDictionary:gradedWorkDictionary];
        [results addObject:gradedWork];
        [self addNewGradedWork:gradedWork forCourse:course];                                               
     }
}
[self saveChanges];
```

The error I get is as follows. It crashes when it hits savechanges.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Unable to save the changes'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.There was one attribute which was required, however I did not save it, i changed it to optional it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is `ListOfGradedWorks` a `NSManagedObject`? If so, you have to insert a new `NSManagedObject` using `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ListOfGradedWorks" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];`

Comment: OK, so which code is doing the insert.`[results addObject:gradedWork];`? Or `[self addNewGradedWork:gradedWork forCourse:course];`?

Comment: self addNewGradedWork is doing the add. it goes inside that code and adds, but when i call [self savechanges] that is when i get the error

Comment: Do you want to add the `gradework` to `course`? Or do you want add `course` to `gradework`. And also is the relation between `gradework` and `course` a one-to-one relation?

Comment: I am trying to add gradedwork to course and the relationship is 1 course can have many gradedwork

Comment: OK but from the code above I could only see you add `course` to `gradework` like this `gw.course = course;`. I think you also need to add the `gradework` to `course`, something like `[course addGradeworkObject:gradework];`

Comment: I have this in my NSMANAGEDOBJECT (course.h), - (void)addGradedWorksObject:(GradedWork *)value;

Comment: Yes I know. But what I mean is you have to manually add the new-created `gradework` to that `course`. Like after `gw.course = course;` just add another line `[course addGradeworkObject:gradework];`

Comment: Nope that didn't do it still getting same problem

Comment: Have you got any exception message other than `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Unable to save the changes'`, or maybe print out the `error.localizedDescription`

Comment: I figured it out, there was one attribute which was required however I was not adding that in. I changed it to optional it worked. Thanks for  taking time and looking into it, really appreciate it.